# regex: eliminate all numbers between slashes

Tags: python, regex, substring, substitution

Expected: `http://some_url.com/api/v1/1/2/3/4" -> http://some_url.com/api/v1/*/*/*/*/`
What I use:

```
re.sub(r"/\d+/?", "/*/", str(url), flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Actual: `http://some_url.com/api/v1/*/2/*/4/`

Comment: Is the last `*` in your desired result missing on purpose? You don't want to replace the last digit with an asterisk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
/\d+(?=/|$)
/\d+(?![^/])
```

and replace with `/*`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rBhzFB/1).

In Python:

```
url = re.sub(r"/\d+(?=/|$)", "/*", url)
```

**Details**

- `/` - a `/` char
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?![^/])` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if the next char is not a character other than `/` (so, end of string or `/` are required immediately to the right of the current location, same as with the positive `(?=/|$)` lookahead)

See [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/G8wfJX):

```
import re
url = 'http://some_url.com/api/v1/1/2/3/4'
url = re.sub(r"/\d+(?=/|$)", "/*", url)
print(url)
# => http://some_url.com/api/v1/*/*/*/*
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use

```
/\d+(?=/|$)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/jwP4Nw/1).